# html5 currentTime and volume changes not taking effect

Tags: javascript

I must be doing something wrong. Trying to set arrow hotkeys for videos to skip through the timeline and adjust the volume. Console logs return the desired new values, but they are not set.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('VIDEO');
    if (vid.length) {
        var vol = vid[0].volume;
        var time = vid[0].currentTime;
        var start = vid[0].seekable.start(0) + 10;
        var end = vid[0].seekable.end(0) - 10;

        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            if (start < time) {
                time = time - 10;
                console.log(time);
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            if (vol < 1.0) {
                vol = vol + 0.1;
                console.log(vol);
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            if (time < end) {
                time = time + 10;
                console.log(time);
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            if (0.0 < vol) {
                vol = vol - 0.1;
                console.log(vol);
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You are only changing the content of your variables here, that does not magically change the value of the properties you originally read those variable contents from. You need `vid[0].volume = …` to actually _set_ a new volume.

Comment: Related: [pass by value vs reference](https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c), [object getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), [object setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

Comment: I won't make any excuse. Pretty stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating the `vid`.

Let's take an instance for volume updation.
What's happening here is you are taking value out of `vol[0].volume` into another variable 'volume' and upon event you are updating `volume` as a variable not `vid`, which you are using actually. Same goes for other keys (start, end and time).

Update `vid` as well.